# Student Test Scores Calculating Average incorrectly

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, structure, average

I have an assignment to build a Student Test Scores application.
I have a structure to hold a student name, an array to hold 5 test scores, and an average score. I have created an a array of structures for 6 students. User input is setup through text boxes. I need to calculate the average for each student. 
Assignment requirements: 
The application should have structure that stores: Name (a string), Test Scores (an array of 5 doubles), and Average ( a double) . It should have an array of 6 structure variables to match the 6 students.It should allow the user to enter the data for each student, and calculate the average test score for each. The user needs to be able to save, read and print data to/from file etc.

It should not accept scores below 0 or above 100.

I have read several posts for this but have not been able to resolve with the existing posts and have spent the last 2 days trying to resolve.  Right now I am not getting the correct averages.
I will also need to be able to print and retrieve the information, but I am first going to resolve this.  I have tried both 5 and 6 in the max counts for student and 4 and 5 for the max counts for tests.  I believe the numbers I have are correct but many of the posts had different numbers but when I use these numbers I am getting a count of 7 for students when I run in debug mode so I am not 100% sure but do believe this is correct.  It appears the sum is not adding correctly and I have tried numerous ways to fix and even tried to initialize back to 0 before moving onto the next number but nothing I have tried so far seems to work.  Thus the reason for a different Try Catch statement for each group of grades.  I left for now just in case I may need to keep separate.

Here is my code.  Any help is appreciated.
fyi-For some reason the code will not start at the Imports System.IO when I post so the initial code under 'Enter code here' is not showing as vb.  Please let me know how to fix for future posts.

Thanks!

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    'Class level variables
    Const intMAX_STUDENTS As Integer = 5  'Number of Students
    Const intMAX_TESTS As Integer = 4  'Number of Tests
    Private strFilename As String = "StudentReport.txt"    'Document File name

    Private student(intMAX_STUDENTS) As StudentRecord   'Array for student names

    Structure StudentRecord

        Dim strStudent As String
        Dim dblTestScores() As Double
        Dim dblAverage As Double
    End Structure

    Sub CalcAverage()

        ImportNames()

        'Variable to hold the total of the grades.
        Dim dblGradesTotal0 As Double = 0
        Dim dblGradesTotal1 As Double = 0
        Dim dblGradesTotal2 As Double = 0
        Dim dblGradesTotal3 As Double = 0
        Dim dblGradesTotal4 As Double = 0
        Dim dblGradesTotal5 As Double = 0

        'Add scores to the array
        For intIndex = 0 To intMAX_STUDENTS
            ReDim student(intIndex).dblTestScores(4)  'Scores per student
        Next

        Try
            'Get grades for first student
            student(0).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade00.Text))
            student(0).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade01.Text))
            student(0).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade02.Text))
            student(0).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade03.Text))
            student(0).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade04.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each a As Double In i.dblTestScores
                    dblGradesTotal0 += a
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg0.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal0 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try

        Try
            'Get grades for second student
            student(1).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade10.Text))
            student(1).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade11.Text))
            student(1).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade12.Text))
            student(1).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade13.Text))
            student(1).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade14.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each b As Double In i.dblTestScores
                   dblGradesTotal1 += b
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg1.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal1 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try

        Try
            'Get grades for third student
            student(2).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade20.Text))
            student(2).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade21.Text))
            student(2).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade22.Text))
            student(2).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade23.Text))
            student(2).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade24.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each c As Double In i.dblTestScores
                    dblGradesTotal2 += c
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg2.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal2 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try

        Try
            'Get grades for fourth student
            student(3).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade30.Text))
            student(3).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade31.Text))
            student(3).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade32.Text))
            student(3).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade33.Text))
            student(3).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade34.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each d As Double In i.dblTestScores
                    dblGradesTotal3 += d
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg3.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal3 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try

        Try
            'Get grades for fifth student
            student(4).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade40.Text))
            student(4).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade41.Text))
            student(4).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade42.Text))
            student(4).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade43.Text))
            student(4).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade44.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each e As Double In i.dblTestScores
                    dblGradesTotal4 += e
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg4.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal4 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try

        Try
            'Get grades for sixth student
            student(5).dblTestScores(0) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade50.Text))
            student(5).dblTestScores(1) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade51.Text))
            student(5).dblTestScores(2) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade52.Text))
            student(5).dblTestScores(3) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade53.Text))
            student(5).dblTestScores(4) = ValidInput(CDbl(txtGrade54.Text))

            For Each i As StudentRecord In student
                For Each f As Double In i.dblTestScores
                    dblGradesTotal5 += f
                Next
            Next

            lblAvg5.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal5 / intMAX_TESTS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Be sure to enter a valid numeric score")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileOpen.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileSave.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFilePrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFilePrint.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFileExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFileExit.Click

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuReportClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuReportClear.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuHelpAbout_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuHelpAbout.Click

        MessageBox.Show("This contains information regarding the Student Test Scores Application")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

        CalcAverage()
    End Sub

    Public Function ValidInput(ByVal score As Double) As Double

        If score >= 0 And score <= 100 Then
            Return (score)
        Else
            Return MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid test score between 0 and 100")
        End If
    End Function

    Sub ImportNames()

        student(0).strStudent = txtStudent0.Text
        student(1).strStudent = txtStudent1.Text
        student(2).strStudent = txtStudent2.Text
        student(3).strStudent = txtStudent3.Text
        student(4).strStudent = txtStudent4.Text
        student(5).strStudent = txtStudent5.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: For a better chance of getting a response from the community, I suggest you more specific with what is working and what isn't, include any error messages, and trim down your codes to just the relevant portion. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.  In the future, please post only the relevant code, not everything.  In this case, the relevant code would be one of the `Try-Catch` blocks were you get the scores and average, not all of them plus the rest of your code.

In any event, without knowing for sure exactly what you're seeing, I think the reason your averages aren't coming out correctly is because of the way you are calculating them.  For example:

```
For Each i As StudentRecord In student
    For Each f As Double In i.dblTestScores
         dblGradesTotal5 += f
    Next
Next
```

The outer loop will go through all the structures in the `student` array.

The inner loop will then sum all the scores for that student.

And then you go to the next student....and add the sum of all of that's students scores to the sum of the previous students'scores.

You only need one loop, for the scores for that student.  You already know the index of the structure in the array, so this:

```
For Each f As Double In student(5).dblTestScores
    dblGradesTotal5 += f
Next
```

Then this line:

```
lblAvg5.Text = CStr(dblGradesTotal5 / intMAX_TESTS)
```

Will give you the average for that student.

A couple more minor things to consider.

1. Your `Try-Catch` blocks are doing the exact same thing every time.  Refactor that code into a method (`Sub`) and save your fingers and keyboard :)
2. In your `ValidInput` function, you specify the return type as `Double`, but in your `Else` block you return `MessageBox.Show`.  I'm not even sure that would compile, but VB.NET isn't as picky as C#.  In any case, return a double in the `Else` that signifies an error (-1 would be good) and pop the message box in the method that called `ValidInput`.

**Input Validation Example**

Validating user input is vital, and its good that you're doing so.  There's an old saying in programming - "Never trust the input from a user."

The challenge with your current approach is that you're trying to return one of two items, depending on the validation result, and you can only return one type from a method (unless you use an `out` parameter).

Generally, I prefer to use `TryParse` when attempting to convert types as it will return a boolean value for whether the conversion (parse) was successful or not, and the result of the parse in an out parameter (the second parameter).  This prevents ugly runtime errors if the conversion fails.  Additionally, the `CDbl` function is a hold-over from Visual Basic (pre .NET), and it's generally considered better to use the built-in .NET conversion operators.

One way to do this would be as follows:

```
Dim score As Double

If Double.TryParse(txtGrade50.Text, score) AndAlso (score >= 0 And score <= 100) Then
    student(5).dbltTestScores(0) = score
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid test score between 0 and 100")
End If
```

Note the use of `AndAlso` in the above `If` statement - this provides short-circuit logic.  If the `TryParse` fails it won't evaluate anything else.

The downside to the above is that now you have a lot of code to repeat.  Another downside is that you're evaluating the input right before assigning it to the array, and you're not giving any indication of which input was wrong to the user.

I'd suggest validating all the input before assigning the values to the array of structures - that way you could tell the user which values were wrong and they could correct it and try again.

The important thing here is to ensure that the data is correct (within required limits) *before* you process it.  Anything else has a strong potential to get very ugly and messy quickly.

Final note - in .NET, Hungarian Notation is generally not considered best practice (i.e., `dblGradesTotal5` is an example of Hungarian Notation - where you prepend a variable name with the type it is).  A simple `gradesTotal5` is normal.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I updated all my code and the averages are now working perfect.  I have not been able to figure out how to get the ValidInput function to work.  Even though the did work before, I would rather learn the right way to code so I really appreciated you feedback.  Public Function ValidInput(ByVal score As Double) As Double

        If score >= 0 And score <= 100 Then
            Return (score)
        Else
            Return MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid test score between 0 and 100")
        End If
    End Function

Comment: I need to add, you had mentioned to use the -1.  I added it in the Return as -1 and also (-1) but in both cases it took it as a value and used it to calculate the average.  So I should clarify that I am not understanding how to use the -1 or if I should be maybe using something else in the function to validate for input between a range of number that would give the user a message box if improper data is entered.

Comment: @cccstudent - I'll take a look and answer later tonight when I get home.

Comment: @cccstudent - Ok - added some more ideas.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, considering how much time I have spent on this problem this was fairly simple to re-write.

Comment: Sorry, it timed out and thought it saved what I finished typing.  I was saying this worked great but the only issue I am still having is it is not stopping to code to continue executing.  I does give the error message as it needs to but then it continues on and calculates the average of just the valid scores within range.  So the average is using the 4 valid number and dividing by 5 instead of forcing the user to enter valid data before continuing on.  I tried finding info in my book but it showed as you had noted.  Is there some type of catch statement I need to add?

Comment: I also wanted to mention how AWESOME your help has been.  Your explanations are so detailed and easy to follow.  I has really helped me understand and learn much better so THANK YOU so much for your time.

Comment: I added "Exit Sub" to each TryParse statement and works great.

Comment: @cccstudent - Glad I was able to help.  I've never been a fan of just dumping a bunch of code for an answer - code with an explanation provides a lot more (for the original poster and anyone who comes along later), IMO.   Sounds like you figured out the validation issue as well.  Another way to do the validation is to hook into one of the `TextBox` events (like `TextChanged` or `LostFocus`, that way you can provide immediate feedback to the user.  Best of luck to you in your course and happy programming :)